# a function that defines a final list using loops and tuples

Tags: python, loops, tuples

i want to define a function that returns all the possible pairing of two giving tuples (including backwards). im new to python and having difficlty writing the correct function.

**its supposed to look like this:**

```
>>> first_tuple = (1, 2)
>>> second_tuple = (4, 5)
>>> mult_tuple(first_tuple, second_tuple)
((1, 4), (4, 1), (1, 5), (5, 1), (2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 5), (5, 2))
```

**this is what i wrote and it doesnt work in any scenerio:**

```
def mult_tuple(tuple1, tuple2):
 sofit = []
 for x in tuple1:
  for y in tuple2:
   sofit.append(x, y)
   sofit.append(y, x)
 return sofit
```

I WOULD APPRICIATE YOUR HELP

forgive my english

**THANK YOU!**

Comment: check `itertools` module you can use combinations

Comment: @deadshot Nope combinations only returns `[(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (4, 5)]` which is not equal to `[(1, 4), (4, 1), (1, 5), (5, 1), (2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 5), (5, 2)]` as expected. But you could run combinations on the given tuple as well as the reverse, then deduplicate it to account for stuff like (1,1).

Comment: If the same value is in both tuples, should there be one or two pairs in the result? Does the order of pairs matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, note that append takes one argument so you need to pass the pair as a tuple:

```
first_tuple = (1, 2)
second_tuple = (4, 5)


def mult_tuple(tuple1, tuple2):
    sofit = []
    for x in tuple1:
        for y in tuple2:
            sofit.append((x, y))
            sofit.append((y, x))
    return sofit

answer = mult_tuple(first_tuple, second_tuple)
print(answer)
```

output:

```
[(1, 4), (4, 1), (1, 5), (5, 1), (2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 5), (5, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from itertools import product

def mult_tuple(a: tuple[int, ...], b: tuple[int, ...]) -> tuple[tuple[int, ...], ...]:
    return tuple(t for p in zip(product(a, b), product(b, a)) for t in p)
    # If you want to remove duplicates use below:
    # return tuple(set((t for p in zip(product(a, b), product(b, a)) for t in p)))    

first_tuple = (1, 2)
second_tuple = (4, 5)
print(mult_tuple(first_tuple, second_tuple))
```

**Output:**

```
((1, 4), (4, 1), (1, 5), (4, 2), (2, 4), (5, 1), (2, 5), (5, 2))
```

Comment: FYI, your desired output in your question is a *tuple* of tuples not a *list* of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Since @ItayB has already answered your question about the algorithm, I am going to give you another way to do it.

The `itertools` module consists of many useful functions, one of which is `combinations()`

The code:

```py
tuple(
    set(
        list(combinations(first_tuple + second_tuple, 2))
        + list(combinations(reversed(first_tuple + second_tuple), 2))
    )
)
```

We run it reversed as well because your requirement specifically asks for both (1,5) and (5,1). Another approach could've been to use list comprehension to reverse the tuples, an exercise I am leaving to OP.

Admittedly, this is a poor use of the function, especially because of the syntax. I am sure somebody could point out some improvements. But the point was to introduce the very helpful `itertools.`